# Trying to maintain state between components and questions about conditional rendering based on wallet login

Tags: reactjs, use-state, metamask, ethers.js

I'm very new to all of this and I've been stuck on these two problems for over a week, reaching out to the community to better understand the issue.

Here is the project have Frankensteined together: https://codesandbox.io/live/ec9a16d7ef6

I have a button in the navbar to login in with Metamask. I have another button on the 'nft collections' page to mint an NFT that shows up after you are logged in. My issue is that button only shows up after a refresh or switching between pages and I want it to update automatically. I'm assuming that the state (currentAccount) isn't being passed through components properly but I'm having difficulty understanding useState.

My second problem I'm trying to work through is creating a conditional render on the navbar that will include another page that can be accessed when a user has a specific NFT collection in their wallet. Again, I'm brand new to all of this so even just some examples to look at or helpful tutorials would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: We cannot view the content of that link without signing in. Please include your code here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.